# Parse scripts to extract address

Tags: script, c++

I want to parse a script with `c++` to gain an output address from it.
can anybody introduce a suitable library or a sample code which extract addresses from scripts ?

Comment: You can look at the code for decodescript in the Bitcoin source. That outputs addresses (if they exist), so should do what you want

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at libbtc (https://github.com/libbtc/libbtc).

There is a function `btc_script_classify()` which will return what script type it is (P2PK, P2PKH, P2SH, P2WPKH, P2WSH) and it will return data elements (usually the RIPEMD160 of the pubkey).